# Release mode crashes when building react-native app using xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

> Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling
>   runApplication)

when running in release mode a react-native app

xcode: 10.1
react-native: 0.57
When running a react-native app in release mode, it crashes and shows warning message as follows

It is working fine while running as debug mode.

```
2019-02-11 15:33:04.330531+0800 EASE[1709:691989] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2019-02-11 15:33:04.639426+0800 EASE[1709:691855] =======>>>>-[ViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]
2019-02-11 15:33:04.639721+0800 EASE[1709:691855] ================ViewController :going initWithNibName, storyBoard goto ===========
2019-02-11 15:33:04.639739+0800 EASE[1709:691855] ================ViewController :start sync===========
2019-02-11 15:33:04.641529+0800 EASE[1709:691855] ===========Here is the synchronization when the program starts============
2019-02-11 15:33:05.069459+0800 EASE[1709:691855] The application is in the foreground and is active
2019-02-11 15:33:05.468 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Can't find variable: n
2019-02-11 15:33:05.467943+0800 EASE[1709:692012] Can't find variable: n
2019-02-11 15:33:05.470 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: n
2019-02-11 15:33:05.469853+0800 EASE[1709:692009] Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: n
2019-02-11 15:33:05.471 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-02-11 15:33:05.471115+0800 EASE[1709:692012] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-02-11 15:33:05.476228+0800 EASE[1709:692009] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: n', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: n, stack:
<unknown>@1163:26828t@1163:474
<unknown>@1163:788t@1163:474
<unknown>@1163:703t@1163:474
<unknown>@1163:588t@1163:474
<unknown>@1163:418355v@2:1483
<unknown>@1162:69v@2:1483
<unknown>@1161:376v@2:1483
<unknown>@1160:592v@2:1483
<unknown>@1159:572v@2:1483
<unknown>@1158:661v@2:1483
<unknown>@998:5169v@2:1483
<unknown>@948:263v@2:1483
<unknown>@946:98v@2:1483
<unknown>@945:49v@2:1483
<unknown>@944:78v@2:1483
<unknown>@943:79v@2:1483
<unknown>@942:49v@2:1483
<unknown>@718:79v@2:1483
<unknown>@717:66v@2:1483
<unknown>@716:51v@2:1483
<unknown>@715:116v@2:1483
<unknown>@714:148v@2:1483
<unknown>@713:176v@2:1483
<unknown>@705:180v@2:1483
<unknown>@704:183v@2:1483
<unknown>@668:223v@2:1483
<unknown>@659:271v@2:1483
<unknown>@658:28v@2:1483
<unknown>@657:138v@2:1483
<unknown>@528:128v@2:1483
<unknown>@343:418v@2:1483
<unknown>@11:58v@2:1483d@2:866global code@2177:4'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x23b373ea0 0x23a545a40 0x105030e30 0x10502d238 0x23b37b600 
0x23b259530 0x23b25a114 0x105045030 0x10508be7c 0x10508bbd8 
0x10817f824 0x108180dc8 0x108188e6c 0x108189b60 0x108193bfc 
0x23af900dc 0x23af92cec)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
NSException
(lldb)
```

App doesn't crash when running in both release mode and debug mode

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: got the same issue. Did anyone find a solution?